# is there a JavaScript implementation of the Inverse Error Function, akin to MATLAB erfinv()?

Tags: javascript

is there a JavaScript implementation of the Inverse Error Function?
This would implement the Gauss inverse error function.  Approximations are ok.

Comment: "Approximations are ok" the other option being... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why yes.  There is.

The following code uses built-in JavaScript functions and implments Abramowitz and Stegun's algorithm as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions):

```
    function erfinv(x){
        var z;
        var a  = 0.147;                                                   
        var the_sign_of_x;
        if(0==x) {
            the_sign_of_x = 0;
        } else if(x>0){
            the_sign_of_x = 1;
        } else {
            the_sign_of_x = -1;
        }

        if(0 != x) {
            var ln_1minus_x_sqrd = Math.log(1-x*x);
            var ln_1minusxx_by_a = ln_1minus_x_sqrd / a;
            var ln_1minusxx_by_2 = ln_1minus_x_sqrd / 2;
            var ln_etc_by2_plus2 = ln_1minusxx_by_2 + (2/(Math.PI * a));
            var first_sqrt = Math.sqrt((ln_etc_by2_plus2*ln_etc_by2_plus2)-ln_1minusxx_by_a);
            var second_sqrt = Math.sqrt(first_sqrt - ln_etc_by2_plus2);
            z = second_sqrt * the_sign_of_x;
        } else { // x is zero
            z = 0;
        }
  return z;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

function provided earlier in this post did not work for me... NaN result on a 33meter circle with confidence 65% represented as 65.0 ...   I wrote the following based on an equation listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions and it worked fine:

```
var _a = ((8*(Math.PI - 3)) / ((3*Math.PI)*(4 - Math.PI)));

function erfINV( inputX )
{
    var _x = parseFloat(inputX);
    var signX = ((_x < 0) ? -1.0 : 1.0 );

    var oneMinusXsquared = 1.0 - (_x * _x);
    var LNof1minusXsqrd  = Math.log( oneMinusXsquared );
    var PI_times_a       = Math.PI * _a ;

    var firstTerm  = Math.pow(((2.0 / PI_times_a) + (LNof1minusXsqrd / 2.0)), 2);
    var secondTerm = (LNof1minusXsqrd / _a);
    var thirdTerm  = ((2 / PI_times_a) + (LNof1minusXsqrd / 2.0));

    var primaryComp = Math.sqrt( Math.sqrt( firstTerm - secondTerm ) - thirdTerm );

    var scaled_R = signX * primaryComp ;
    return scaled_R ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative implementation of Abramowitz and Stegun's algorithm (equivalent to ptmalcolm's answer, but more succinct and twice as fast):

```
function erfinv(x) {
  // maximum relative error = .00013
  const a  = 0.147  
  //if (0 == x) { return 0 }
  const b = 2/(Math.PI * a) + Math.log(1-x**2)/2
  const sqrt1 = Math.sqrt( b**2 - Math.log(1-x**2)/a )
  const sqrt2 = Math.sqrt( sqrt1 - b )
  return sqrt2 * Math.sign(x)
}
```

[image: equation for approximation to inverse error function]

You can test the speed with `console.time("erfinv"); for (let i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {erfinv(i/1000000000)}; console.timeEnd("erfinv")`

The `if` statement optimization is commented out as it doesn't seem to make a difference - presumably the interpreter recognizes that this is all one equation.

If you need a more accurate approximation, check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations).