# Quantile/Percent Point/Percentile/Inverse Cumulative Distribution function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, math, normalization, normal-distribution

Is there a way to calculate the [quantile/percent point/percentile/inverse cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of a normal distribution in JavaScript? If so, how? The input is a value beween 0 and 1, and the desired output is the one shown below, where 0 gives -inf, 1 gives inf, and 0.5 gives 0:

[image: ppf plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a JavaScript implementation of the Inverse Error Function, akin to MATLAB erfinv()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556685/is-there-a-javascript-implementation-of-the-inverse-error-function-akin-to-matl)

Comment: @PeterO. No, but I used the answer I found there to get the function I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by taking ptmalcom's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556685/is-there-a-javascript-implementation-of-the-inverse-error-function-akin-to-matl) for the function `erfinv` and applying the formula printed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function) to get the percent point function:

```
    const ppf = function(x) {
    return Math.sqrt(2) * erfinv(2*x-1)
    }
```